# variables nil after switching tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have TabBarController with 3 tabs. In my `.m` file i have 2 properties.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ingredientItems; //array to store ingredient items entered
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *directionsItems; //array to store direction items entered
```

I go to the Ingredients tab and add a couple of values. I can see them in the log. The `ingredientItems.count=2`

Then i change over to the other tab for directions. Now the `ingredientItems is nil`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which .m file are these two properties declared?

Comment: they are both in the same .m file. AddRecipeViewController

Comment: Is that your tab bar controller subclass or the view controller representing one or more of the tabs?

Comment: its the view controller for the tabs

Comment: OK. Then you have multiple instances of the view controller, one for each tab. Each instance has its own copy of the properties.

Comment: then how can i share the variables?